# join two columns to one column if they are numeric in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

This is what I am using. The problem is with it being numeric.
I also need a `-` to separate.

```
COALESCE([STORE_RECEIPT_NUM], '') + '-' + COALESCE(e.[STORE_ID], '')
```

Example:

```
STORE_RECEIPT_NUM = 12345
STORE_ID = 611
```

The column RECEIPT_NUM should read 12345-611

However, it adds them and comes out  12956

If I use columns that are not numeric it works great

Comment: Cast to varchar first

Comment: in sql server `+` is used for both addition and concatenation.  when numeric data types are involved you get addition, when string data types are involved you get concatenation, when both string and number data types are involved you get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what type of SQL you are using but try:

```
CAST(COALESCE([STORE_RECEIPT_NUM], '') AS VARCHAR(9)) 
+ '-' 
+ CAST(COALESCE(e.[STORE_ID], '') AS VARCHAR(9))
```

Comment: Choose a specific size (like 9) for those varchars, but otherwise this is it.